# Why can't I change a variable located in a .py file imported into a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-import

Say I've got a file a.py:

```
a = 0

def give_a():  
    return a
```

Then I've got a Jupyter notebook with the following two cells:

```
from a import *
```

.

```
a = 10  
print(give_a())
```

This outputs 0 instead of 10.

Why doesn't it output 10 and how can I fix it so it will?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't output 10, because the `a` in `a.py` and the `a` in your Jupyter notebook are two different variables. You should take a look at the scope of variables in Python, see for example [this chapter in an online textbook](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html).

In brief:

```py
a = 0

def give_a():  
    return a  # refers to the variable a declared in the module
```

```py
a = 10  # is declared within the Jupyter notebook
print(give_a())  # is a function in a.py
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say `print(give_a())`
You are only returning the global variable, a = 0 defined in your file. It doesn't know about a = 10. Instead, pass a variable to your function like this

```
def give_a(a):
    return a
```

Then when you import the function, do

```
print(give_a(10))
```

Comment: This would be good, though I'll have to look more into how to make it work for me. In my actual use case, `def give_a(): return a` is being used as a value in a dictionary. Like: `dict_a = {'give_a' : give_a}` so that I can call it with `dict_a['give_a']()`. Then again, I suppose I can use `dict_a['give_a'](a)`. I'll try that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in your notebook `a` refers to the module `a.py`, so the variable that is in the module should be called `a.a` in your notebook.

In some cases it is better to import code from `.py` files into notebooks using ipython's `%run` or `%load` commands. Read the documentation on these two and I am sure you will start including them in your notebooks. They can be used in ipython CLI as well as in the web interface.

Comment: I'll look into %load. I've got two notebooks working together. The first is already using %run to use info in the second. The second needs some info from the first, and if I use %run to point them at each other, I get infinite recursion. That's why I'm importing some code from the first notebook into the second one as a module.

Comment: Perhaps you could break the included code into smaller chunks to avoid the looping. I only use `import` to import modules, apart from that all I do is `%run -i` to inject the code from files to the notebook or CLI session.